# Is it "safe" to evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} +x}$ as follows?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

If I want to evaluate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} +x},$$
is it valid to use regular arithemtic rules to come to
$$\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} 1}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} +\lim_{x \to \infty} x}?$$
Evaluating existing limits gives
$$\frac{1}{0 +\lim_{x \to \infty} x},$$
but writing something such as
$$\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$
does not seem legal, although it feels intuitive that the limit is $0$ from the first expression.

Is there a more sound way of stating this? Perhaps with different laws of limits which I seem to be lacking knowledge of? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits **when (a) the limits are defined** and (b) the limit of the denominator is non-zero

Comment: Right, so it looks like the assumptions I made were incorrect. How else could we show that the limit is $0$?

Comment: It's $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{{1} +x^2}$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to0} \dfrac{x}{{x^2} +1}$

Comment: @SeanXie Hint: $\,0 \lt\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} +x} \lt \frac{1}{x}\,$ on the domain of interest.

Comment: @dxiv So we can conclude that the limit is $0$ by the Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: Yes, the Squeeze Theorem works

Comment: Multiplying the numerator and denominator by $x$, as J. W. Tanner suggests above, is probably the most natural way to approach this limit. However a slight shortcut would be to divide the numerator and denominator by $x$, which would yield $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^2} +1}$

Comment: @SeanXie Right, and this is an easy squeeze here.

Comment: The answer you accepted is actually wrong. It is possible and relatively easy to define limits in a manner that supports infinities, using the affinely extended reals. Nevertheless, what you wrote is still wrong because you cannot anyhow push the "limit notation" around and hope that the resulting expression has the same value. I suggest you go and study *proper* real analysis first from a good text such as Spivak's "Calculus", *before* you go and learn about the affinely extended reals.

Comment: @user21820 "*It is possible and relatively easy to define limits in a manner that supports infinities, using the affinely extended reals.*" $\;-\;$ That is correct, of course, but it is certainly not part of the "*regular arithmetic rules*" that OP's question and my answer are about.

Comment: @dxiv: The error in the asker's attempt is **not** in the *arithmetic rules* regarding infinities. It is **perfectly correct** in the affinely extended reals to have $1/(1/∞+∞) = 1/∞ = 0$. What is wrong is precisely what I said: "*anyhow push the "limit notation" around*". That is why your post is actually wrong. You should not ascribe the error to *arithmetic with ∞* when it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @dxiv: Even then, despite your post being wrong for the technical reason I explained, you can see that I didn't downvote it, because it gave the correct method. If you would just improve your wrong phrasing regarding "arithmetic rules with ∞", it would be great.

Comment: @user21820 My answer is (obviously) based on my reading of the question, and assumptions on OP's background and context. It is certainly possible to read the question and/or context differently, and provide a different yet equally valid answer. If you post, for example, an answer based on arithmetics on the extended reals (with the necessary primer or pointers) then I'll +1 it, but it was not my intention that *my* answer covers that.

Comment: @dxiv: I'm not asking you to cover that at all. I think you missed my objection. It is that the error is *not* in the arithmetic with infinities (so you can't say it is). The error, as I said, is in anyhow pushing the "limit notation" around, which is *prior* to the arithmetic with infinities. It doesn't matter whether we use the extended reals or not; that error in the asker's question remains an error. And that's the real point that (in my opinion) must be made clear for your answer to be (completely) correct.

Comment: @user21820 I edited the answer and added a note to that effect.

Comment: @dxiv: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is it valid to use regular arithmetic rules to come to $\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} 1}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} +\lim_{x \to \infty} x}\;$ ?

No, because the second term in the denominator does not have a (finite) limit, and you cannot mix "*regular arithmetic rules*" with infinities.

> Is there a more sound way of stating this?

You could derive it (correctly) as follows:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} +x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x^2} +1} = \frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} +1} = \frac{0}{0 + 1} = 0
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ] Additional notes, prompted by the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264836/is-it-safe-to-evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-frac1-frac1x-x-as-follo?noredirect=1#comment8872674_4264836).

> is it valid to use regular arithemtic rules to come to
> $\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} 1}{\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} +\lim_{x \to \infty} x}?$

This *would* follow by the "*regular arithmetic rules*" from the limit properties for sums and products *if* all limits existed and were finite. But one of the limits is not finite in this case, so it does not follow by those rules.

If the OP is familiar with (and is allowed to use) the extended reals line, then the result would follow from the [arithmetic operations for extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations), in particular $\,\frac{1}{0 + \infty}=0\,$.

> Evaluating existing limits gives
> $\frac{1}{0 +\lim_{x \to \infty} x}$

This is wrong in general, because it is not allowed to take the limits of only *some* of the expressions involved. Doing so can easily give bogus results e.g. $\,\lim \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\lim \left(1+0\right)^n=1\,$.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in comments, your method is not valid because the hypotheses for the quotient and sum limit laws are not satisfied.  However, the common technique of (convert to polynomials, then) factor out the big part works.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + x}
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x} + x} \cdot \frac{x}{x} \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{1 + x^2}  
\end{align*}
Here the largest power of $x$ appearing in the numerator or denominator is $2$, so factor out $x^2/x^2$.  Continuing the display,
\begin{align*} 
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x^2}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1/x}{1/x^2 + 1}  \right)  \\
&=\frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1/x}{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1/x^2 + 1)}  \\
&=\frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1/x}{\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1/x^2 + \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 1}  \\
&= \frac{0}{0 + 1}  \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

This may seem like "put something in just so we can take it and a little bit more out again", and this is a valid observation.  Clearing the nested denominators is just to make it very clear where the power of $x$ is coming from.  However, we can do the same thing in the original form:
$$  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \left( \frac{x}{x} \cdot \frac{1/x}{1/x^2 + 1} \right)  $$
equally arranging for the numerator and denominator to have finite limits with the denominator not having limit $0$.

Comment: Can we construct an exact counterexample, such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0, ~~\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=+\infty$$ But, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+g(x))≠+\infty$$?

Comment: @lonestudent : No.  For $f$ and $g$ satisfying the separate limits, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $N > 0$ such that for all $x > N$, $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ and $g(x) > 1/\varepsilon$.  So $f(x) + g(x) > 1/\varepsilon - \varepsilon$, which gives us $f+g \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.